# Can I upgrade Xcode to support a newer version of GCC to learn C++0x?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, gcc

I would like to jump in learn C++0x, which has matured to a level I'm happy with.

Xcode on Snow Leopard 10.6 is currently at GCC 4.2.1, and the new features I'd like to try, like std::shared_ptr, lambdas, auto, null pointer constant, unicode string literals, and other bits and pieces, require at least 4.3 (I believe).

Ideally I'd use Xcode but I'm not even sure if you can manually upgrade the compiler for Xcode.  Is this possible?

Otherwise, what is the best way to install a different version of GCC that doesn't interfere with the rest of the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up downloading the latest Intel Compiler for Mac trial, and it does what I need.  It's a good way to test the waters without messing with your system.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers/

Comment: this doesn't look free - if I am not mistaken, it goes for 90 days only

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at LLVM and Clang and see if those can accomplish what you're after, if you want to use XCode. Apple has been making a shift away from GCC and towards LLVM/Clang due to licensing reasons.

Comment: I use Clang from time to time, but unfortunately LLVM/Clang's C++0x support isn't where it needs to be yet.

http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html