# Can I use C++11 with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, c++11, clang

I am considering the use of some C++11 features (like `auto` for instance) in some cross-platform projects (Windows+Mac). On Windows, Visual Studio supports parts of the upcoming C++11 standard that would allow me to simplify parts of the code base so naturally I would be interested in starting to use these features.

But as far as I am aware, the current XCode version (3.2.4 + GCC 4.2) does not support any C++11 features at all. Can I upgrade the GCC version or the CLang version somehow? Or should I just bite my tongue and wait for Apple to package a new version sometime in the future?

Comment: Look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946887) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002395).

Comment: For a more positive outcome, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837992/update-gcc-on-osx

Comment: Regarding Clang: I believe it achieved reasonable C++03 support recently, but C++0x is still a far goal. For example, support of variadic template is work in progress and move semantics / rvalue references have not been implemented yet.

Comment: Variadic templates work fine for me with clang.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 had finally added support for C++0X:

1. In the project build settings screen, switch on "All" options.
2. In the "Build Options" section, set compiler to "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0".
3. Scroll down to "Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 - Language" section and set "C++ Language Dialect" to "C++0X" and "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++".

The std::move(), move constructor and R-Value reference are known to work as expected, and I'm testing on the std::thread and std::atomic.

Comment: @ RichardLiu, what about the `GNU++0X` option for the `C++ Language Dialect` and the `libstdc++` option for `C++ Standard Library`? When do they shall be used?

Comment: I have had a look in `/Developer/About\ Xcode.pdf` and yes, it says that C++11 is supported, but when I use `-std=gnu++0x` it spits out `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=0x++"`! Should I use `clang++` instead?

Comment: @errordeveloper, so far I had only successfully compiled C++11 WITHIN Xcode IDE. I don't know how to enable C++11 in command line or makefile. Sorry.

Comment: @RichardLiu: XCode normally uses `clang++` when compiling, not `g++`, which is why C++11 support fails when trying to use `g++` from the command line (because the ancient `g++` XCode gives you doesn't support it). Just FYI.

Answer (score 9):

**======= Update 2012: =======**

Start with Clang - Many C++11 features are now available in Clang. It's included with Xcode.

**======= Original answer from Jan 2011: =======**

intel's compiler may be the cleanest way to go at this time.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-composer-xe/

clang's promising, but not particularly stable or featured wrt c++0x features. c++ is still very new for clang.

gcc: relatively mature, but you'll have to write and maintain your compiler plugins for xcode.

you can also specify custom scripts, but that is a pain to maintain... unless you go all out and create an adaptor tool.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode uses the GCC or the Clang C++ compilers. Any features supported by those compilers are fair game. GCC's C++ compatibility page is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and the Clang C++ compatibility page is [here](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/ggreif/CallInst-operands/www/cxx_compatibility.html).

Comment: True but GCC support stops at 4.2 which is starting to get a little long in the tooth

Answer (score 0):

I've found auto, decltype(), range based "for (:)" work in a cross platform project (LLVM for MacOSX,iOS, gcc/linux, MSVC 10/windows).

lambdas & variadic macros don't appear to work under LLVM yet sadly.

Comment: MSVC 10 and 11 don't support range-based for. Clang, on the other hand, *does* support variadic templates just fine.