# How to update to C++11?

Tags: c++, macos, unix, gcc, c++11

I am new to programming, so have never experienced a language update. With the release of C++11, I want to make use of all the new features such as lambda expressions and threads. I know I can do this with external libraries but using native language features would be more convenient.

I am using gcc 4.2.1 on Mac OS X Snowleopard in Xcode 3.2.6

**What all do I need to do and update to start using C++11 features?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482026/can-i-use-the-latest-features-of-c11-in-xcode-4-or-osx-lion ...

Comment: @StilesCrisis The question is referring to Lion, while I am asking about Snow Leopard...

Comment: Well, it's certainly only more challenging on Snow Leopard. I'd guess MacPorts is the same and Xcode is a lost cause.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can update to Xcode 4.1 (or whatever the most recent version you can get for Snow Leopard is) and get a new compiler with a few more C++11 features. There are some posts here on Stack Overflow about getting better support for C++11 in Xcode 4.1 on Snow Leopard.

But even the latest compiler available through Xcode does not support some C++11 features like lambdas. To get the best C++11 support you'll want to install a newer compiler, gcc 4.6 or 4.7, or Clang.

I frequently build the latest version of clang from source. It's not difficult to do if you're familiar with building other open source software. I use the git repos for clang and llvm, `http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git` and `http://llvm.org/git/clang.git`. You can also find instructions on their website for getting started: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html. Once you have the source for clang and llvm it's just `./configure && make && sudo make install`. (you might want to run the tests before installing, since this is directly out of the repository. After `make` do `make check` in the llvm directory, and once that passes cd down to tools/clang and run `make test`. If everything is okay then `sudo make install`)

I don't remember if Snow Leopard included libc++ or not, so you may need to get that as well. http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Once everything is built and installed you can do:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp && ./a.out
```

and you should have just about the best C++11 support around.

Recent patches in clang have really improved support for the last features you're likely to notice as a new C++ programmer. There are still a few bits and pieces left, but as of 3.1, and  as far as I'm aware, clang has every C++11 feature that either gcc 4.7 or VC++11 has and more besides. libc++ also has the fewest gaps in terms of C++11 standard library features IME (though I think VC++'s standard library will also be pretty complete once they catch up on language features, e.g. char32_t and char16_t as native types so that the standard's mandated specializations for those types can be used).

Comment: Snow Leopard does not have an up-to-date libc++, you have to build it. However, it is unclear from the libc++ docs how to do it with a modern clang++ . They provide instructions for Linux, or Mac binaries compiled for [Mountain] Lion, ie. OS X 10.7 and 10.8.

Comment: @user465139 Do the instructions to do `cd libcxx/lib; export TRIPLE=-apple-; ./buildit` not work on Snow Leopard?

Comment: + clang++ -c -g -Os -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -std=c++0x -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -nostdinc++ -I../include ../src/exception.cpp
../src/exception.cpp:18:12: fatal error: 'cxxabi.h' file not found
  #include <cxxabi.h>

Comment: Oh, I guess Snow Leopard doesn't include libc++abi or something. You'll also need to get and build that: http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/

Comment: Thanks for the useful hint, +1. However, libcxxabi does not build, either, looks like Catch-22:   + clang++ -c -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wsign-conversion -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wunused-variable -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wchar-subscripts -Wmismatched-tags -Wmissing-braces -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict-overflow=4 -Wunused-parameter -Wnewline-eof -I../include ../src/cxa_aux_runtime.cpp
../src/cxa_aux_runtime.cpp:14:10: fatal error: 'typeinfo' file not found
#include <typeinfo>
         ^

Comment: @user465139 you can point libc++abi at your libc++ headers manually instead of using `-libstd=libc++`. Alternatively you can take advantage of the fact that exceptions in libc++ were designed to be ABI compatible with the gcc 4.2 exceptions and just use the old stdlib instead of libc++ when building libc++abi

Answer (score 1):

Basically you only need to get a toolchain that has support for the new features. In macosx that would be either GCC or clang++. You might need to download/compile a particular version if needed (i.e. if the feature that you want to try is not in a prepacked compiler bundle but is available in the repository).

I downloaded and compiled the latest trunk of clang++ from subversion to do some testing, and installed g++ 4.6 with macports in Snow Leopard. I remember that I had some issues with the setup of the environment, but don't quite remember which of the compilers gave me problems or how I solved them. Google is your friend there :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have homebrew installed, from [this article](http://george.sudarkoff.com/c11-on-a-mac/), just two steps:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install gcc --enable-cxx --enable-fortran --use-llvm
```