# How to choose the toolset to run gradle with c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, gradle, clang

Gradle 1.7 came out recently with some inspiring support for C++.

I have built and compiled my project in my arch linux box using g++ and it worked great! The build.gradle is this simple:

```
apply plugin: "cpp-exe"

binaries.all {
    if (toolChain == toolChains.gcc) {
        compilerArgs "-std=c++11"
        linkerArgs "-lboost_program_options"
    }
}

defaultTasks "mainExecutable"
```

Now I'm trying to build it on my MacOs, but there gradle tries to run it with g++ which doesn't support the -std=c++11 (remember, mac's g++ version is 4.2.1).

Is there a way to tell gradle to use clang++ ? I'm happy to add another if statement to the build.gradle if that's possible.

Comment: You can always update your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271637/how-to-update-to-c11++:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.7 ships with support for g++ and Visual C++. You can file a feature request at http://forums.gradle.org.