# LLVM&Clang support of C++11

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, llvm, clang

I have some code written by me for MS VC++10. I use C++11 and, in particular, expressions like

```
std::function<int (int)> f =...;
auto it = v.begin();
for_each(it1, it2,[&](int& i) { ++i;});
```

Now I'm trying out MacOS and XCode with llvm&clang and my code can't be compiled! The question is why? Perhaps, I shall specify an option to use c++11. In this case, where can I fix it in xcode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need Xcode 4.2.

In your build settings, search for "c++0x" and set the "C++ Language Dialect to C++0x [-std=c++0x]".  Then search for "libc++" and set the "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++".

Not all C++11 facilities are available.  For example lambdas are not yet supported.

Comment: Many C++11 features are also supported by the Xcode 4.1 clang, but you have to put the options in the 'other flags' fields. Also the Xcode version of clang disallows using libc++ on OS X pre-Lion, so even if you install libc++ you can't use it. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226753/osx-lion-xcode-4-1-how-do-i-setup-a-c0x-project/7236451#7236451

Comment: @bames53: If you want to use libc++ on Snow Leopard, I can help you.  Go here (http://libcxx.llvm.org/) and follow the directions for 10.6.  You need a helper lib I host on my personal website.  You can contact me directly if you need help with this.  Xcode 4.1 does not support libc++, but only gcc 4.2.  gcc 4.2 gives no library support for C++11 (though there is some tr1 support).

Answer (score 5):

For a list of C++11 features Clang currently supports, see [this nice list](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). Lambda expressions (and syntactically related initialzer lists) are currently not implemented.

Your only choice for now (until Clang devs implement lambda support) is using MacPorts' GCC 4.5/4.6 compilers.

The extra command-line option would be `-std=c++0x` (in the next version of Clang and GCC it will be the proper `-std=c++11`).

Comment: Note that the list in question are only for what is supported in the repo. What you get from XCode is almost certainly an earlier version.

Comment: Nicol: true enough, but it's easy (and fast) enough to build Clang yourself ;-)