# Any reason not to use c++0x for iOS development?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++11, llvm

Is there any reason *not* to use c++0x and the libc++0x standard library for iOS development?

Comment: Probably not for any reason that wouldn't apply to using any other variant of c++ for iOS development; your SDK uses Objective-C, and c++ classes and Objective-C classes do not mix nicely in terms of syntax, conventions, and memory management paradigms.

Comment: @aroth Yeah, I use a thin Objective-C layer and do the rest in C++.

Comment: Sounds like a pain.. why not Objective-C?

Comment: @CollinHockey I am using OpenGL ES, not UIKit, so...

Comment: @CollinHockey: you can easier port game later to different platforms. C++ is more available that Obj-C.

Comment: Does Apple now support C++11?

Comment: @MFH Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4574246. Although it isn't working for me...

Comment: @Jay: Interestingly Apple uses the same technique more often than not: Core Animation is a thin Objective-C layer on top of C++, Core Audio uses a C interface on top of C++, WebKit puts a slightly thicker layer of objc on C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use C++ to be more portable to other platforms later, it might be smart to hold off for awhile. Some targets may not yet have a C++0x compiler, or the company policy may be to use an old but trusted compiler for game release builds.

Answer (score 2):

@Amigable, most if not all current C++ compilers suppor C++0x to some extent. After all it is slowly become standardized.

Comment: Now you have enough rep to post a comment. To "some extent" is not always going to cut it.