# How to disable Xcode C++11 warnings?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, compiler-warnings

Is there a way i can disable these warnings?
[image: The warnings]

They kind of annoy me a bit because it always opens the issue navigator.

Comment: Change project properties to tell it that you are using C++11? Must be a setting somewhere. :)

Comment: Change project settings instead of silencing the warning. Here is [a link to the answer that explains how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7791906/335858).

Comment: Yes. Fix your code so that there are no warnings.

Comment: @H2CO3 but I want to use C++11 :P

Comment: @notrodash then write your code in C++11 and then fix it.

Comment: @H2CO3 I followed the instructions that dasblinkenlight linked, i am not getting any warnings or compile errors anymore and the application runs fine. So my code must be right.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Could you possibly post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use C++11 with Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574246/can-i-use-c11-with-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the settings of your project to allow for C++11.

Here is [a link to an answer that explains how it is done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791906/335858).