# Why does the xcode IDE think `friend` is a reserved-word

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, keyword, reserved-words

I've been working on a personal project and have the below code in a new class that I have created:

```
@property (readonly, getter = isFriend) BOOL friend;
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it and when I build it, it works compiles absolutely fine but when we look at this line of code in the `xcode IDE` it looks like

[image: Code snippet screenshot]

My question is why does the `xcode IDE` seem to think that the word `friend` is a keyword/reserved-word?

Comment: c++ thinks it is, is your compilation unit Objective-C++?

Comment: FWIW, the same thing happens when a method is named `delete`, even in non-(Objective-)C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably because `friend` is a reserved word in C++. See [Friendship and inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).

You could try modifying your xCode settings for the compiler to see if the IDE picks this up. See
[Can I use C++11 with Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574246/can-i-use-c11-with-xcode/7791906#7791906)

Comment: To be honest it doesn't bother me that much it was more of me just wondering, I will just use a different name. Thank you for your answer, will leave it a day or two and see what other answers I get but otherwise I will happily accept this.