# Enable C++ initializer lists with g++ in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, g++, initializer-list

I created a new Xcode project by selecting "external build system" and set the build tool to `/usr/bin/g++` (which is what I used when compiling from the terminal). Now I am trying to initialize a 2d vector of doubles using an initializer list, but get the error:

`Non-aggregate type 'vector<vector<double>>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list`

This is the code I am trying to compile:

```
vector< vector < double > > dct_mat =
{
    {0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536},
    {0.4904,  0.4157,  0.2778,  0.0975, -0.0975, -0.2778, -0.4157, -0.4904},
    {0.4619,  0.1913, -0.1913, -0.4619, -0.4619, -0.1913,  0.1913 , 0.4619},
    {0.4157, -0.0975, -0.4904, -0.2778,  0.2778,  0.4904,  0.0975, -0.4157},
    {0.3536, -0.3536, -0.3536,  0.3536,  0.3536, -0.3536, -0.3536,  0.3536},
    {0.2778, -0.4904,  0.0975,  0.4157, -0.4157, -0.0975,  0.4904, -0.2778},
    {0.1913, -0.4619,  0.4619, -0.1913, -0.1913,  0.4619, -0.4619,  0.1913},
    {0.0975, -0.2778,  0.4157, -0.4904,  0.4904, -0.4157,  0.2778 ,-0.0975}
};
```

How can I enable initializer lists? I don't care if I need to change my g++ for something else. I just don't know what compiler should I use. If you know which compiler will work for me, please also state how to tell Xcode to use it.

Comment: Which g++ version are you using? Try `g++ --version`

Comment: Did you try adding `-std=c++11` compiler flag?

Comment: This is the output of 'g++ --version'

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: @AlexTerreaux Ouch, GCC 4.2.1 is stone age! You should have 4.7 at least, or merely 4.9. Consider updating your machine!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574246/can-i-use-c11-with-xcode. @πάνταῥεῖ: This is clang masquerading as g++ on Mac OS. The compiler version is fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ adding -std=c++11  fixed the compiling error. However, I get a segfault when running it. If I comment out the initializer list, it works good.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux _"However, I get a segfault when running it."_ Sounds like this is an orthogonal problem,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean unrelated? I would have thought that too, but I am not even referencing the vector anywhere in the code. Just having that initialization makes it crash.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux The vector isn't the root of your crash. I just pasted the listed vector of vector definition a clean `main()` on my Mac (Xcode 5.1.1, same toolchain as yours). No errors. Constructs the vector of vectors fine. Your crash is somewhere in your code; not this def.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I was declaring it as a global variable. Doing so inside a method fixed. Why do you think this is?

Comment: Will this be fixed if I declare it in a .h file? :(