# Including C++ (Boost) header in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, cordova, boost

I'm including https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore into my project, but since my project is a Cordova project (I'm attempting to tweak Cordova project to mix it with native components using VideoCore), it seems incompatible to Cocoapods and I'm building the project manually.

Now it's complaining that tuple is not found on `IMetaData.hpp`

```
#ifndef videocore_IMetadata_hpp
#define videocore_IMetadata_hpp

#include <map>
#include <tuple> // **this line**
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <videocore/system/util.h>
```

I suspect that it's `tuple.hpp` from `Boost`, which I included as well. But it does not find it.

Help appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**

The solution to my original problem is pretty straightforward, I should in the build setting make sure XCode is compiling in C++11.

However, I found out that I don't have to jump through hoops to incorporate Pods dependencies into a Cordova project.

Instead of doing `pod install`, do

`pod install --no-integrate`

With this Cocoapod does not attempt to build an XCode workspace, which currently is incompatible with Corodva until a newer version comes out ([as discussed here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5921)). Until than, the `--no-integrate` switch create a Pods project which you can just drag into your Cordova project as a sub-project. (If unsure how to integrate, [this helps](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/). All Pod projects are compiled into libPod.a which you should include.)

Comment: It's a C++11 header, check if compiler command line contains  `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.

Comment: That header isn't from boost. It's a standard header and requires at least c++11

Comment: @AntonSavin Alright, after consulting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574246/can-i-use-c11-with-xcode and adding C++11 support problem is fixed, thanks. If you want post below I can accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: if you want to use c++ code your file has to be .mm and not .m (objective-c file), so, are you putting that code on a .m or a .mm?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks for reminding me. The code is from the VideoCore itself so it should not have been the problem. Actually Anton Savin already points me to the right direction and the problem is already solved. Thank you nevertheless. :)

Comment: In stack overflow-etique, should I delete this question since it's similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574246/can-i-use-c11-with-xcode?

Comment: sure, you can delete it

Comment: Actually, I'll leave it on and edit some more. I found out that I don't need to go through the hoops to incorporate pods project into Cordova this way.